# How to use optional parameters inside a WHERE clause using HQL?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to be able to perform a query which filters on the available rows and if non is available return all results. How can I accomplish this in pure `HQL`, without using a `Criteria`?

The snippet below, compiles but the query does not return any result.

```
@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends CrudRepository<Article, Long> {

    @Query("FROM Article a " +
            "JOIN a.manufacturer m " +
            "WHERE " +
            "(:search_term IS NULL OR :search_term = '' OR a.description LIKE CONCAT(:search_term, '%')) AND " +
            "(:manufacturer_id IS NULL OR m.id = :manufacturer_id) " +
            "ORDER BY f.priority DESC")
    Page<Firmware> search(@Nullable @Param("search_term") String searchTerm,
                          @Nullable @Param("manufacturer_id") Long manufacturerId,
                          Pageable pageable);

}
```

Comment: You can't easily do this from a single query.  It might be possible with a UNION, but the code would be ugly.  Instead, I recommend getting your result using HQL, and if that result set be empty, then return `select *`.

Comment: That statement looks fine to me. Could you add the final query executed by Hibernate, the search term you are using and some example data that you expect to get returned?